# actix-web session management without sending session data (via a cookie) to the client

Tags: session, cookies, rust, session-cookies, actix-web

I am writing a web application in Rust/actix-web and I am looking for a way to store data related to sessions on the server side. The session data does not contain any user data or such. The web app is a game/simulation of a specific mathematical problem on big graphs. Hence, the session data contains information attached to the nodes of the graph.

I found the `actix_session` API which makes it possible to store session data and send it with a cookie but I don't want the whole session data to be sent because it might be very large and the client should only receive junks of it when required.

Is there a way to maintain (cookie) sessions without sending the session data directly with the cookie or are there even other solutions than cookie sessions?

Comment: Have you tried `JWT`?